# IdentityServer4 GetProfileDataAsync is not called for Identity Token, only Access Token

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

Using IdentityServer 4 (4.1.2), I've added a class implementing the IProfileService interface. The method GetProfileDataAsync is supposed to be called several times (for each token), but my method is only called for the Access Token (ClaimsProviderAccessToken).

```
  public class LocalUserProfileService : IProfileService
  {
    private readonly IIdentityProviderUserService _identityProviderUserService;

    public LocalUserProfileService(IIdentityProviderUserService identityProviderUserService)
    {
      _identityProviderUserService = identityProviderUserService ??
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(identityProviderUserService));
    }
    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
      var subjectId = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
      var claims = (await _identityProviderUserService.GetUserClaimsBySubjectAsync(subjectId)).ToList();
      
      Debug.WriteLine($"Adding claims to {context.Caller}");
      context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
      
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
      var subjectId = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
      context.IsActive = await _identityProviderUserService.IsUserActiveAsync(subjectId);
    }
  }
```

I could manage to only use my access token to get the custom claims, but I would like to know why the code is not called for the identity_token as I prefer to have the claims in both tokens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you set the [AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/models/client/) flag to true? Otherwise the claims for the ID-token will be provided through the UserInfo endpoint instead.

A common way to reduce the size of the ID-token is to not include all the claims in the ID-token. Large tokens will also result in large session cookies. By default, the tokens are stored inside the session cookie.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you for the tip and the information regarding the size. It actually rings a bell (read it somewhere) now that you remind me. Thanks again